# Django: Avoid users uploading files, use their local storage instead?

Tags: python, django

So I have a Python script that extracts data from .ifc (3D models for the AEC Industry) files to a .csv or .xlsx and I would like to make it available in a web app.

The files can get pretty big (> 400MB) and users are rarely owners of these files, so they are probably not allowed to upload them.

So I am looking for a way to avoid the file upload. Is something like that possible with a Django App?

Or should I look into creating a desktop app with some other framework?

Comment: Django happens on the server, which means the file has to be uploaded. Everything that happens on the client (browser) has to be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Django runs on the server-side. it needs files to be accessed on the server so users have to upload them. so Django definitely is not your answer. If you insist on using python, you can check out [pyscript](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript). but it's pretty new. if you want users to be able to access your app in the browser, you can try rewriting your code in javascript. otherwise, several options are available.

Comment: I was just typing what @KlausD. said, so +1. I might add that nearly every Python web app I've build has ended up either moving all the technical functionality to the client side, in JS, because of issues like this (and the speed), or building a regular web app, as you're suggesting, but making it super easy for a customer to deploy on a virtual private cloud.

Comment: Tnx everybody for the explanation :)